# Issues with viewport object not rendering, can see in viewport render but not in actual render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I have the following setup [image]

in viewport the grass can be seen perfectly but as soon as I go to render [image]

the grass disappears, what is the reasoning for this? I have had numerous times faced this issue and everytime I'd start a new project it would work but then some other times it wouldn't work

Here is the blend file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some problems in the file:

- The river is created with *Geometry Nodes* and a Shrinkwrap modifier, but it creates a desolate mesh.
- The grass is then instantiated on the plane as a function of this, and is visible in the viewport, but not when rendering, because a different resolution is used here.

...all in all, this is an unfavorable chain of modifiers and events.

I have therefore restructured the whole file a bit:

- first I create a solid river, which is also correctly trimmed at the edges and where no vertices are swept somewhere under the carpet.
- I moved it to the collection, where all other objects are located, just like the ground plane.
- Then I created a separate object for the final compositing of the objects, where I use *Geometry Nodes* to generate the scene.

And now everything fits:

[image]

Now this is a bit of a useless answer, because all this probably won't help anyone but you, but at least it might help you.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks again for your help you have been amazing!, just wondering though what do you mean by desolate mesh and what can I do to not have this issue again because I've had other projects with same issue, where I would just restart the project completely I've done that 2-3 times and this was the latest case